# php swap table rows columns (array)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, for example `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`.
I want it in a table.  I can do this:

```
|-------------------------------|
|   1   |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
|-------------------------------|
|   6   |  7  |  8  |  9  |  10 |
|-------------------------------|
```

But I want this:

```
|-------------------------------|
|   1   |  3  |  5  |  7  |  9  |
|-------------------------------|
|   2   |  4  |  6  |  8  |  10 |
|-------------------------------|
```

The number of columns is fixed (for example 5). The number of rows must be homogeneous, for example `(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)` or `(3, 3, 2, 2, 2)` or `(3, 3, 3, 3, 2)`, NOT `(4, 3, 3, 2, 2)` and NOT `(2, 2, 3, 3, 3)`...

How can I do this?

PS: the table is in html!

Comment: show what you got so far

Comment: Did you try anything? Get some code in here.

Comment: I don't have an idea How to do that!

Comment: Use modulus to manipulate your array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$size = count( $array);
$cols = 5;
$rows = $increment = ceil( $size / $cols); // It looks like this need a ceil()

for( $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    for( $j = $i; $j < $size; $j += $increment) {
        echo $array[$j];
    }
}
```

**[Here is a working demo.](http://codepad.org/83zvzkw8)**

Comment: Yeah, mixed up `$count` and `$size`, try again.

Comment: I added a demo - You'll have to test your edge cases, perhaps adding in a `floor()` or `ceil()` call to the calculation for `$rows` / `$increment`.